# Android Logcat spams a lot of garbage

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, spam

Recently my lolcat started to spam a lot of things. I think that was because some errors in my codes, but today I create a new project and running, and the logcat started to spam again. My apps run without problem, but all this spam is annoying because I can't see my own log's `(
Log.d("TAG", "Hi")`; for example). Hope anyone can help me.
There's an example of my logcat output running an empty app:

```
04-08 00:36:15.460  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Items in Video cursor: #39 | position: #-1
04-08 00:36:15.465  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Existing locations #39
04-08 00:36:15.469  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Fill mediaValues took: 0 ms
04-08 00:36:15.471  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Fill video took: 31 ms for content://media/external/video/media
04-08 00:36:15.501  20043-22809/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 516K, 46% free 9415K/17252K, paused 1ms+6ms, total 28ms
04-08 00:36:15.519    1017-1171/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.android.providers.calendar for content provider com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProvider2: pid=29499 uid=10011 gids={50011, 3003, 1028, 1015}
04-08 00:36:15.525    1017-1703/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.motorola.context (pid 29470) has died.
04-08 00:36:15.591  29499-29499/? I/CalendarProvider2﹕ Created com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarAlarmManager@42295e38(com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2@4228d9f0)
04-08 00:36:15.685  29483-29512/? I/ActivityModePolicy﹕ Transition mode: meeting from: 2 to: 2 token:
04-08 00:36:15.688  29483-29512/? W/AbstractModePolicy﹕ Cannot update state for: meeting, from: 2, to: 2
04-08 00:36:15.692  29483-29512/? I/ActivityModePolicy﹕ Active mode set to: ModeModel[id=3, key=sleep, category=activity, priority=1, version=1, status=5, token=sleep_1428465600000, startTime=1428465600163]
04-08 00:36:15.779    1017-2965/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.motorola.contextual.smartrules2 (pid 29483) has died.
04-08 00:36:15.782    1017-1066/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
04-08 00:36:15.782    1017-1066/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: ConnectedState
04-08 00:36:15.782    1017-1066/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: L2ConnectedState
04-08 00:36:15.796    1017-1066/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: X
04-08 00:36:15.797    1094-1094/? I/SBar.NetworkController﹕ onReceive: WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION Received
04-08 00:36:15.804  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Items in Audio cursor: #642 | position: #-1
04-08 00:36:15.810    1094-1094/? I/SBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster: wifi: mWifiConnected=true Wifi=zz_moto_stat_sys_wifi_signal_2_fully_wide Activity=(none) in=false out=false Accessibility="Dos barras de Wi-Fi"
04-08 00:36:15.818  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Existing locations #643
04-08 00:36:15.915  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Fill mediaValues took: 0 ms
04-08 00:36:15.917  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Fill audio took: 446 ms for content://media/external/audio/media
04-08 00:36:15.975  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Items in Image cursor: #785 | position: #-1
04-08 00:36:15.993  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Existing locations #785
04-08 00:36:16.138  19215-19228/? D/DtMediaProvider﹕ Fill mediaValues took: 0 ms
04
```

EDITED 04-08-15:

I don't know what's happening with my Android Studio. I tried to delete some configuration files and even reinstall Android Studio, but nothing works. I just apply a filter like biddestroyer suggest and kind of work. The spam decreases, but still there. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You can filter log based on your tag in your editor.

Comment: In your command line just type: adb logcat -v threadtime | findstr /I TAG      This should give you only your logs.

Comment: Android Studio should automatically set a filter for you so you see your own log outputs, but it's a little glitchy. Try checking Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration or restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ/Android Studio, you can add custom log filters by package for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case of Eclipse you can apply filter to see log related to your application. You can do this by clicking plus icon in top left corner of your log cat screen.